# Fusion Charts FusionTime making a time-series chart from mySQL

Tags: java, html, mysql, fusioncharts

I am a beginner at all things coding but need some help with Fusion Charts if anyone can help.

I have followed along with tutorials already for Fusion Charts linking it to MySQL database and displaying a chart with no issues.

However, I would like to display a time-series chart, which uses FusionTime. This requires the data to be in a Datatable. " FusionTime accepts data in rows and columns as a Datatable".

I cannot find any examples online for taking SQL data and converting into a datatable with data and schema which it seems to require. This is different from the way fusioncharts works.

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/create-your-first-chart-in-fusiontime

My SQL database contains many tables and many columns within it, so will need to select the appropriate column to display.

I would appreciate any advice anyone can provide. The main problem is I don't know how to get the SQL database into a data and schema file to display with fusiontime. This is to display on a webpage hosted locally.

Many thanks for any time you can provide to help with this

Comment: Could you provide a few more details, like the table structure, what the schema should look like, any code you've written, etc.?

Comment: FusionTime takes data in an Array of array format. No matter what your database is, you need to generate the data in an array of array format. Mostly all the UI libraries follows the same standard. Write a script that can generate your sql data to the expected format in a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. Here is a link to the tutorial to create a time-series using the data and schema: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/getting-started/create-your-first-chart-in-fusiontime. My issue is to get the SQL data from my table into this format. It has 420 rows and around 100 columns. I just want to select two columns however.

Comment: Thank you Dip686. I will try and research how to do this

Comment: @CJU Which server-side technology are you using? is it java?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the document to implement the case it would help you out-

1. Establish the connection with MySQL Database using the hostname, username, password and database name.
2. Execute the query to get the list of players from DB and store them in a variable.
3. Iterate over the result set to build an array of maps where each map consists of two keys namely: label and value.

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/tutorials/php-mysql-charts

```
<?php
    //address of the server where db is installed
    $servername = "localhost";
    //username to connect to the db
    //the default value is root
    $username = "root";
    //password to connect to the db
    //this is the value you specified during installation of WAMP stack
    $password = "password";
    //name of the db under which the table is created
    $dbName = "test";
    //establishing the connection to the db.
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
    //checking if there were any error during the last connection attempt
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Also refer this - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/javascript-charts-using-php-and-mysql-with-fusioncharts-xt-part-2/

Answer (score -1):

ft needs a json, you must write a file from php type json

like this
.....

```
 $result = json_encode($dataIngGast, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
         //echo $result;
         
         $arquivo = "column-line-combination-data-gasto-ingreso-finanzas.json";
         $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
         fwrite($fp, $result);
         
fclose($fp);
```